# How to prevent my langchain agent to user other tool. It should only use the vector store data

Tags: python, langchain

I am developing a chatbot for a pdf QNA. while using the agent, if the user question is not in the uploaded document it should show like I dont have information. But in my case it showing in the observation part after that the the agent is still executing and giving answer from the internet. I need to prevent this action and show like I dont know.

this my code

```
def answer(query):
    docs = db.similarity_search(query)
    return chain({"input_documents": docs, "human_input": query}, return_only_outputs=True)

tools = [
    Tool(
        name = "chapter light vector store",
        func=lambda q: str(answer(q)),
        description="Useful when you need to answer questions about the chapter on light."
    )
]
agent = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True)

agent.run("give me five points")

template = """You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human.

Given the following extracted parts of a long document and a question, create a final answer.
The answers should be from the content in the documnet. 
If the answer is not found in the document say I dont have information about this.


{context}
{chat_history} 
Human: {human_input}
Chatbot:
"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["chat_history", "human_input", "context"], 
    template=template
)
```